# Camel-SEDA in spring DSL - slow performance

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, apache-camel

There are two routes in camel spring DSL:

```
<route id="master">
  <from uri="quartz..."/>
  <to uri="mongodb:testDb?database={{testDB}}&collection={{testCollection}}&operation=findAll" />
  <split streaming="true">
    ...
    ..
    <to uri="seda:slave"/><br>
  </split>
</route >

<route id="">
  <from uri="seda:slave"/>
  .......
  .....
</route >
```

**Issues and Questions:**

**Use case 1:**
Mongo find all return say 100k documents and I am using splitter pattern and calling sub route.Initially I used "direct" component instead seda. so It took around 30 mins to complete the process.

**Use case2:Enable Multi thread options**

I wanted to use multi threading option in Splitter EIP pattern and I changed the direct component to seda because direct is synchronous. After changed to seda component the result was quite different i.e very slow for 120 records its taking one minute.

**Question:**

Is there any performance issue in the seda component with multi threaded Environment?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have chance to enable the parallelProcessing option of splitter? BTW, you can dig the performance issue by monitor the threads processing time.

Comment: Yes,I have enabled parallelProcessing as well as executorServiceRef . And found that default seda consumer thread is one and I increased to 10and20 and tested it.Performance was increased but got so many duplicate insertion in DB i.e we are calling webservice then doing mongo insert in to DB in second route .I have tried with direct component with multi threading options too . Performance improved but we got so many duplication records also in DB

Comment: Can you find out why your route made the duplicate insertion? Did you use the right key when doing the insertion?